# Setup a basic WebSocket mock in AWS ApiGateway

Tags: websocket, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to setup an extremely simple WebSocket mock within AWS ApiGateway. However, every attempt I've tried gives me an error:

```
13:36:52 (X33uOGUfIAMFq7w=) Extended Request Id: X33uOGUfIAMFq7w=
13:36:52 (X33uOGUfIAMFq7w=) Verifying Usage Plan for request: X33uOGUfIAMFq7w=. API Key: API Stage: redacted/prod
13:36:52 (X33uOGUfIAMFq7w=) API Key authorized because route '$connect' does not require API Key. Request will not contribute to throttle or quota limits
13:36:52 (X33uOGUfIAMFq7w=) Usage Plan check succeeded for API Key and API Stage redacted/prod
13:36:52 (X33uOGUfIAMFq7w=) Starting execution for request: X33uOGUfIAMFq7w=
13:36:52 (X33uOGUfIAMFq7w=) WebSocket Request Route: [$connect]
13:36:52 (X33uOGUfIAMFq7w=) Client [UserAgent: null, SourceIp: redacted] attempts to connect to WebSocket API [redacted].
13:36:52 (X33uOGUfIAMFq7w=) Execution failed due to configuration error: statusCode should be an integer which defined in request template
13:36:52 (X33uOGUfIAMFq7w=) Client [UserAgent: null, SourceIp: redacted] failed to connect to API [redacted].
```

As far as I can tell, I've followed the most basic configuration possible. I do not need any responses or templates, just simple a WebSocket connection that allows me to connect to it and do nothing, or perhaps respond to `ping` requests with a `pong` eventaully.

[image: api route $connect]

All authorizations and API keys are disabled. No request templates or integration responses are setup since I do not need them. Again, the goal is to just be able to have a dumb WebSocket that can be connected to.

[image: no request templates]

However, whenever I try to connect to it, I get a 500 error with the error logs from above about a status code.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://redacted.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Using the following sources (below), I was able to get a quick and loose example AWS API Gateway connection working use MOCK endpoints with web sockets. I'm sure this can be flushed out more to provide an even better understanding of different request/response body messages and codes..

1. First, go to API Gateway, click **Create API**
2. For **Choose the protocol**, select **WebSocket**
3. Give the API a name, and use the example `$request.body.message` for the **route selection expression**
4. Click the **Create API** button
5. Select the new API from the side pane, and click **Routes**
6. Select the **`$connect`** route
7. Under **Route overview**, select the **Mock** radio button for endpoint
8. For the **Request Template**, enter an expression (using 200 for example).
9. For **Template Key**, enter a key (using 200 for example)
10. For the popup window on passthrough behavior, select **No, Use Current Settings** for now
11. Click on the **Template Key** `200`, and enter a template: `{"statusCode" : 200}` and then click the Save button.
    [image: connect integration request]
12. Select **Route Overview** to go back to the **`$connect`** overview page and then select the **Add Integration Response** button
13. Create a response key of **$default**, which will reference the **`$default`** key under **Routes**
    [image: connect integration response]
14. For the **`$disconnect`** route, please repeat steps **7 - 13** for this specific route.
    [image: disconnect route]
15. Once done setting up the **`$disconnect`** route, please select the **`$default`** route under the **Routes** pane.
    [image: default route]
16. Create an **Integration Request** the same way that was done for **`$connect`** and **`$disconnect`** (steps **7 - 11**)
17. For **Integration Response** under **`$default`**, we will be setting the route response up slightly different than **`$connect`** and **`$disconnect`** as those 2 routes' responses actually reference the **`$default`** response within their own respective **Integration Responses**.
18. Create a response key of **$default**
19. Enter a **Template Selection Expression** (using 200 for this example)
20. Then create a **Template Key** (using 200 for this example)
21. Click on the **Template Key** `200`, and enter a template: `{"statusCode" : 200, "connectionId" : "$context.connectionId"}` and then click the Save button.
    [image: default response]
22. `{"connectionId" : "$context.connectionId"}` was added to the response payload to show how variables can be used within the response to represent an actual value of the connection.
23. Finally, under the **Actions** dropdown, select **Deploy API**, and enter a deployment stage name. This should generate a WebSocket URL that can now be connected to e.g. (`wss://#######.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test`)
24. Using `wscat` via cli, I am now able to connect to my WebSocket URL (see source below for installing wscat): `wscat -c wss://#######.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test`
    [image: cli websocket]

**Sources:**

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-wscat.html
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=299642&tstart=0

Comment: Very detailed, thank you. I believe point 13. is a bit misleading, since it does not reference the $default route, but it's the $default key.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-selection-expressions.html#apigateway-websocket-api-route-response-selection-expressions

Comment: Thank you for the step by step guide! Helped a lot for getting a good starting point.

Comment: I had to remove the quotes from the statusCode property in the integration requests to get a proper match :(

Comment: The key takeaway for me is that the `$connect` route cannot return a response.

Comment: 24 steps for the simplest possible WebSocket example!

Comment: @RupertRawnsley - can't tell if that is a good or bad thing? Lol, granted this is a few years old now.

Comment: @Woodrow I'm damning the perversity of AWS while simultaneously praising your determination and guile in working around it.

Comment: @EtienneMartin do you mean it is not possible to return something to a client on connect? I fail in retrieving the connection id from a browser but I get it in wscat.
On the client I simply try to get the connectionId from `onOpen` but I don't receive it.

Comment: Correct, this is not possible to return anything from the $connect event. If you look closely at the last screenshot, you can see that @Woodrow pressed enter, which triggered the $default route with the correct response. Learned that the hard way.

Answer (score 8):

I've automated the steps described by Woodrow using CloudFormation so now anyone can reproduce it more easily.
The template can be found here: https://gist.github.com/maatthc/9d2dfe0448733f0ee1624d658fbac80f .
To create a new stack using it you should:

1. Download the template to your machine.
2. Head to Cloudformation in the AWS Console (https://ap-southeast-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) - Change your AWS Region.
3. Click in "Create Stack"
4. Choose "Upload a template file" and use the template you've downloaded.
5. Click Next, give the stack a name and click Next again.
6. Click Next and "Create Stack".

Here's how it looks like for one route:

```yaml
  WebSocketApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
    Properties:
      Name: WebSocketApi
      ProtocolType: WEBSOCKET
      RouteSelectionExpression: $request.body.action

  WebSocketConnectRouteIntegration:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref WebSocketApi
      IntegrationType: MOCK
      RequestTemplates:
        '200': '{"statusCode":200}'
      TemplateSelectionExpression: '200'
      PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
  WebSocketConnectRouteIntegrationResponse:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::IntegrationResponse
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref WebSocketApi
      IntegrationId: !Ref WebSocketConnectRouteIntegration
      IntegrationResponseKey: $default
      ResponseTemplates:
        '200' : '{"statusCode":200}'
      TemplateSelectionExpression: '200'
  WebSocketConnectRoute:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref WebSocketApi
      RouteKey: $connect
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      OperationName: WebSocketConnectRoute
      Target: !Sub integrations/${WebSocketConnectRouteIntegration}
  WebSocketConnectRouteResponse:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::RouteResponse
    Properties:
      RouteId: !Ref WebSocketConnectRoute
      ApiId: !Ref WebSocketApi
      RouteResponseKey: $default

  WebSocketStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage
    Properties:
      StageName: dev
      ApiId: !Ref WebSocketApi
      AutoDeploy: true
    DependsOn:
      - WebSocketConnectRoute
```

Comment: It fails to generate and rollsback. Probably something related to roles. I tried to specify a role for ApiGateway to log in CloudWatch but it also fails saying that the role is incorrect or can´t be applied. I´m pretty new to AWS, does it make sense this error?

Comment: Fixed it, it seems my role didn´t have the proper trust relationship as per https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-role-arn-error/ and after that it didn´t have permissions to POST something or to create new roles, so I gave admin policies. If you know which minimum policies would the Role require, please let me know so that I can grant just the minimum it requires :)
Thanks for your answer!