# AWS - Lambda Authorizer returns error 500

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, http-error

I have set up an AWS API Gateway Web Socket API.

Overview of my setup: Client --(upgrade request)--> AWS API Gateway ----> Lambda Authorizer

My `$connect` route:

[image]

Note that:

- It currently does not have `Integration Response` and `Route Response` yet. Is there problem with it?
- `connect-authorizer` is the name of my Lambda Authorizer

`connect-authorizer` does receive request from the client, but fails to authorize the client!

Below is the code of `connect-authorizer` (refer from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html), `Request-based` function):

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log("Received event", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    callback(null, generateAllow("me", event.methodArn)); // just authorize!

    //callback("Unauthorized"); // if replaced by this line, my Terminal does receive error 401 !
};

const generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
    console.log("generating policy", principalId, effect, resource)

    const authResponse = {};
    authResponse.principalId = principalId;
    authResponse.context = {
        "stringKey": "stringval",
        "numberKey": 123,
        "booleanKey": true
    };

    if (effect && resource) {
        const statementOne = {};
        statementOne.Action = "execute-api:Invoke";
        statementOne.Effect = effect;
        statementOne.Resource = resource;

        const policyDocument = {};
        policyDocument.Version = "2012-10-17";
        policyDocument.Statement = [statementOne];

        authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
    }

    console.log("final authResponse", authResponse)

    return authResponse;
};

const generateAllow = function(principalId, resource) {
    return generatePolicy(principalId, "Allow", resource);
};

const generateDeny = function(principalId, resource) {
    return generatePolicy(principalId, "Deny", resource);
};
```

But I always get error 500 from my terminal `wscat`:

[image: Error 500 from wscat]

Log in `CloudWatch`:

[image]

Is there problem with `Statement: [ [Object] ]`? Why I always receive error 500?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an Integration Response? I believe the `$connect` route should return  an object with the `statusCode` property set to 200.

I remember [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55601297/3725009) helped me when I was struggling while setting things up.